# How we can monitor the network traffic of logs transferred through the rsyslog

Tags: server, syslog, logs, network-monitoring, rsyslog

I'm consolidating the client logs to a centralized server in Ubuntu using the rsyslog deamon. While consolidating the logs, **how can i see the amount of network traffic or file size transferred from the client to server?**

**Is there any way i can do filtering from the client machine before transferring the logs to server?**

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding only selected messages is easy. Put a file with the extension `*.conf` in `/etc/rsyslog.d`.
Name it e.g. `/etc/rsyslog.d/40-forwarder.conf` to have it read *before* the defaults (in `50-default.conf`)
or `/etc/rsyslog.d/60-forwarder.conf` to have it read *after* the defaults:

```
if ( ($programname == "my-binary") or ($syslogfacility-text == "local1") ) then {
    action(type="omfwd" target="my.syslog.server" port="514")
}
```

This will forward all mesages with the given properties to
host `my.syslog.server`, UDP port `514`. If you put `stop` after the
`action`, then no further processing is done for that message.

This means: if you name the file `40-....conf` and add `stop`:

```
if ( ($programname == "my-binary") or ($syslogfacility-text == "local1") ) then {
    action(type="omfwd" target="my.syslog.server" port="514")
    stop
}
```

then the default actions for these messages (like writing them to `/var/log/messages`)
will *not* take place.

As for you other question about network traffic: That is actually another question and
should be posted separately.

---

#### Update

The condition

```
if ( ($programname == "my-binary") or 
     ($syslogfacility-text == "local1") ) then {…}
```

is just an example for a filter. Probably you have some other criteria
to select the messages that should be forwarded to the centralized logging
host.

In this case only those logmessages that were written to the
logfacility `local1` or were issued by some program called `my-binary`
would be forwarded. All others whould not.
You can test the filter with `logger` (the `-t` switch mimicks the
program name):

```
logger -t my-binary    -plocal4.info "This is forwarded ($RANDOM)"
logger -t other-binary -plocal1.info "This is forwarded ($RANDOM)"
logger -t other-binary -plocal4.info "This is NOT forwarded ($RANDOM)"
```

On the remote host, the first two messages should appear, but not the last.

You didn't say what kind of filter should be applied, so I chose an arbitrary
criteria.

See [Filter Conditions](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html) and [RainerScript](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/index.html) for further information
on what is possible with `rsyslog`.

Comment: In the above *conf file, can you explian **$programname == "my-binary"** and **$syslogfacility-text == "local1"**.

Comment: @JasirBinSiddique See the updated answer. You asked whether it is possible to filter the messages
before they are sent to the server. This is just an example of a filter which 
you must adapt to your needs.

Comment: @PerlDuck-I want to forward filtered **FTP authentication related logs, and SSH logs into syslog file in centralized server**. How can i do the filtering?

**How can i create a single log file in consolidated server for FTP logs where logs are coming from different nodes or client?**

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @JasirBinSiddique For `ssh` I'd try `$programname == "sshd"`, maybe `$syslogfacility-text == "auth"` and/or `$syslogfacility-text == "authpriv"`. For `ftp` exists a facility with the same name: `$syslogfacility-text == "ftp"` could work if your FTP server uses that facility.

Comment: @JasirBinSiddique As for your new question about the receiving end: That would indeed be a separate question. I answered your question about filtering messages before sending. /// In your question you wrote that you are consolidating your logs with `rsyslog`. I'm pretty sure then, you already read the rsyslog documentation, especially the section "Rsyslog and rulesets" in https://www.rsyslog.com/guides-for-rsyslog/the-recipies/basic-configuration/.

Comment: @PerlDuck- In which file the **sshd logs will be forwarded from the client to server?**
will i be able to create a separate log file for filtered log in consolidated server?

Comment: @JasirBinSiddique This is a Q&A site. It means _one_ question at a time. It is not a conversation site. You are currently asking the fourth question in a row and apparently haven't used the links to the documentation I offered. The last link I gave literally answers your question about the receiving end. It contains the snippet `file="/var/log/network1.log"`. So what do you guess in which file the logmessages would go or where you could change that filename? You can configure all this. Have you tried any of the code snippets I wrote down?